# How to build a enchanting table

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you build an enchanting table and get lvl 30 enchants on it. Everytime I try it dosent work. I triedputting book shelves around it and nothing and i used obsidian to build the table but it dosent work.

Comment: Have you tried a simple google search? It'll be faster...

Comment: Google is your friend. Please use your friend first.

Comment: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Enchantment_Table

Comment: I've removed the second question from your post. One question per question please.

Comment: @Studoku That edit completely changed the question being asked as he wanted to know how to get level 30 enchantments. Not just the recipe for the table.

Answer (score 10):

To receive an enchantment level higher than 8, you will need to properly place  bookshelves around the enchantment table:

> Nearby bookshelves raise the available enchantment levels; without any bookshelves the experience level cost will never exceed 8.

### Amount of Bookshelves

This table shows the amount of bookshelves required to get higher level enchantments:

[image]

<sub>(Click for larger image)</sub>

You will notice that you need at least 15 bookshelves in the vicinity of the enchanting table to receive level 30 enchantments.

### Placement of Bookshelves

Correctly placing the bookshelves around the enchanting table is key to receiving high level enchantments.

The most simple way of doing this is by surrounding the enchanting table with a one block high border with a gap anywhere in the perimeter (15 bookshelves):

[image]

Another option is to make a corner of bookshelves to one side of the enchanting table two blocks high, this can look very good in the corner of a room (16 bookshelves, however you can delete one of the blocks behind the corner without sacrificing aesthetics):

[image]

### Other Blocks

Other blocks placed around the enchanting table can effect what level you recieve when enchanting.

> For the bookshelves to operate, the 2-high area between the enchanting table and the bookshelves must be completely clear. In addition to torches, objects like snow or carpet will disable the effect of bookshelves:

The carpet in this screenshot will prevent the bookshelves having any effect on the enchantment levels:

[image]

This 'feature' is sometimes used to purposely lower the level of the enchantments, without having to break the bookshelves.

> An easy way to limit the maximum level of enchantment offered is to disable bookshelves by placing torches between them and the enchantment table. That way one can still have the entire 'ring' of bookshelves around the table, but get lower-level enchantments when desired. Breaking the torches will restore the effect of the bookshelves.

You can tell if the bookshelves are contributing to the enchantment levels by focusing on the particles coming out of the bookshelves into the book on top of the enchanting table. If you do not see particles, you either have a block blocking the bookshelves from the enchanting table, or particles turned off in the video settings.

> If the table is surrounded by bookshelves, with one block of air in between, arcane glyphs float from the bookshelves into the book (if particles are turned on).

Notice the particles in this picture:

[image]

---

**Source:** [Enchantment Table](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchantment_Table), [Enchanting](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting) and [Enchantment mechanics](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchantment_mechanics)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to build an Enchantment Table:
[image: Enchantment Table Recipe]

And here's how to get an Enchantment table to give level 30 Enchantments:
[image]